# How to get interface extending another one (aka super) by its super

Tags: java, reflection, interface, guava, extends

Here is my code using Guava:

```
public interface NetSession {
    void connect();
}

public interface HttpSession extends NetSession {
    void useRestApi();
}

class HttpSessionImpl implements HttpSession {
}

class Test {
    NetSession makeProxy(NetSession session) {
        TypeToken<? extends NetSession> sessionTT =
                TypeToken.of(session.getClass());
        TypeToken<? extends NetSession>.TypeSet ifaces =
                sessionTT.getTypes().interfaces();
        //  here we looking for real <? extends NetSession> interface
        Class<? extends NetSession> sessionIface = 
            (Class<? extends NetSession>) ifaces.stream()
                .filter(i -> i.isSubtypeOf(NetSession.class))
                .map(i -> i.getRawType())
                .findAny().orElse(null);
        assert sessionIface != null;
        
        session.connect();
        if (sessionIface == NetSession.class) {
            return session; // as is
        }
        // make extra
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) session;
        httpSession.useRestApi();
    }
}
```

Is there more elegant way to find class of interface by its super?
I mean something like:

```
Class<? extends NetSession> sessionIface = sessionTT.getInterfaceExtending(NetSession.class);
assert sessionIface == HttpSession.class; // is ok in case above
```

With Guava or else make no difference.

Comment: For there to be an actual instantiated interface then its' implementing class instance exists instantiated, that would depend on whether you would actually know what class would be a typeOf . reflection api may be able to do that faster and use loadClass() with a boolean argument whether its instantiated or wanted as new.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no I don't think there is.

However, it strikes me that what you are doing is equivalent to this:

```
NetSession makeProxy(NetSession session) {
    session.connect();
    if (session instanceof HttpSession) {
        HttpSession httpSession = (HttpSession) session;
        httpSession.useRestApi();

        // do something else
    } else {
        return session;
    }
}
```

In short, your complicated Guava code doesn't achieve anything that you can't do *more elegantly* using `instanceof`.

You don't need to use reflection to find an interface if you then just intend to use the interface non-reflectively.

Comment: thanks, you right, in this example using reflection make it complicated unreasonably. in real code i need to wrap object with invocation proxy if it implements extended NetSession (eg HttpSession) and return as is if it just implements NetSession directly. that is why i need a Class of real interface implemented.

Comment: Even so, `instanceof` is probably going to be simpler unless there are multiple (especially unbounded)  different sub-interfaces of `NetSession` that need to be proxied differently.  And if that is the case, your "inelegant" solution may be the only option.  I think it is.

Comment: @НиколайКостин just test for `session instanceof HttpSession` and if so, pass `HttpSession.class` to the proxy generator. Otherwise,  you can also simply pass `session.getClass().getInterfaces()` to `Proxy.newProxyInstance(…)`
 and make it a proxy for all interfaces implemented by the `session`, as it’s easy to handle all of the methods by just delegating to the `session`, unless it’s the specific method you’re interested in. The invocation handler can also check for `method.getDeclaringClass() == HttpSession.class`.